# How to see intuitively that $\kappa_T$ is constant for solids?

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics we define

$$\kappa_T = -\dfrac{1}{V}\left(\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T.$$

By this definition, if we are treating $V$ as a function of $p$ and $T$, then $\kappa_T$ is also a function of $p$ (since we are keeping $T$ fixed), thus it can depend on pressure and temperature.

I've read, though, that $\kappa_T$ is nearly constant for a solid which allows us to treat it as a constant in whatever we have to do.

My question here is: how can we see conceptually that $\kappa_T$ is constant and doesn't depend on the pressure?

Obviously there are other ways to see this: I believe (although I haven't tried yet) that using Statistical Mechanics we could deduce $\kappa_T$ in the same way as we get the specific heat of solids considering the solid as a lattice of harmonic oscillators. This would be a mathematical deduction which could show why $\kappa_T$ is nearly constant.

Another way would be experimentally. We could perform experiments and looking at the data conclude that $\kappa_T$ is nearly constant.

But is there any other, conceptual way, to infer that $\kappa_T$ is nearly constant? Is there any intuitive point of view here?

Comment: I would think that probably isotropy & homogeneity arguments would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The force between atoms in a solid is going to look something like:

[image: Force]

This is obviously not linear, but for small displacements $\delta r$ around the equilbrium position we can expand the force as a polynomial:

$$ F(r_0-\delta r) = A\delta r + \mathcal O (\delta r^2) $$

then drop the terms in $\delta r^2$ on the grounds that they are small. So for sufficiently small displacements we can assume the displacement is linear in the applied force, which will give us a constant compressibility.

And most solids and liquids have a very low compressibility so under most circumstance the displacements of the atoms $\delta r$ are indeed very small. That's why the compressibility is roughly constant.

Once you apply enough pressure to move outside the linear area the compressibility cannot be assumed constant. For example a quick Google found [this data for the variation of the compressibility of water with pressure](http://www.roymech.co.uk/Related/Fluids/Fluids_Water_Props.html):

[image: Compressibility]

Comment: What is pointed with the arrow in the sketch is not the equilibrium position. The value of r there is (depending on the interactions that keep the solid together) ionic, metallic or van der Waals radius of the atoms.

Comment: @linuxick: the arrow points to the value of the spacing in the solid where the net force on the atom is zero. Why is that not the equilibrium spacing in the solid?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, for a short period of time I considered this as energy versus distance curve. I will keep my comment anyway for careless people like me.

Answer (score 1):

We know intuitively from everyday experience that solids are nearly incompressible.  No matter how hard we press on them from all sides, the volume of the solid hardly changes.  It takes a huge increase in pressure to cause a decrease in the volume of a solid (or liquid).  In fluid mechanics, we often treat liquids as being perfectly incompressible.  A liquid or solid being nearly incompressible means that $\kappa$ is very close to zero.